# Filtering a list using Find All with an OR statement

Tags: c#, list, findall

```
if (product_search.Text.Trim() != "")
{
    filteredProductsList = filteredProductsList
      .FindAll(s => s.product.Contains(product_search.Text.Trim().ToUpper()));
}
```

I have the above code that filters a list of products down if the product contains the searched text. However, I want this text box to filter on either `Product` or `Barcode`. If there a way to run `FindAll()` but with an `OR` statement. So filter down to if the product contains the searched text or the barcode?

Comment: Did you try `||`

Comment: Dont ask ever evolving questions, if the question was answered mark it as corrrect, and write another well formatted and reasoned question without lumps of code

Comment: My apologies. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// Search if product_search is not all whitespace string
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(product_search.Text)) {
  // let's extract a local  variable (readability) 
  string toFind = product_search.Text.Trim();

  // it seems you want case insensetive search: let's specify it clearly:
  // StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
  // trick: IndexOf(..., StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 since
  //        we don't have appropriate Contains
  // Finally, you want || - either product or barCode should contain toFind
  filteredProductsList = filteredProductsList
    .FindAll(item => 
       item.product.IndexOf(toFind, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
       item.barCode.IndexOf(toFind, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what type of list this filteredProductsList is, but I am going to assume it is a list of strings, so using linq you can do something like

```
filteredProductsList = filteredProductsList.Where(x => x.product.Contains(toFind) || x.barcode.Contains(toFind)).ToList();
```

alternatively if you just want the opposite selection you can just do

```
filteredProductsList = filteredProductsList.Where(x => !(x.product.Contains(toFind) || x.barcode.Contains(toFind))).ToList();
```